# How to finish this proof of Mersenne primes?

Tags: number-theory

For natural numbers $n$ define $M_n=2^n-1$. Let $p,q$ be prime such that $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $q=2p+1$. By considering $(\frac{2}{q})$ show $q|M_p$.

So far I have shown $(\frac{2}{q})=1$ so $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$ but I don't see how that helps me show  $q|M_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2$ is a square $\pmod q$ we have $$2^{(q-1)/2}\equiv 1 \pmod q\implies 2^p\equiv 1 \pmod q$$.

Comment: Thanks, didn't spot the (obvious) use of Euler's criterion. One more question: for the second part I need to show $M_{23}$ is not prime. Edit: I don't think what I had before was right.

Comment: You have to take $2\cdot 23+1=47$, which must be a prime factor of $M_{23}$ because of $23=4\cdot 5+3$

Comment: Does this make sense: We want to show $M_{23}$ is not prime. So take $p=23 \implies q=47$ then by above $47|M_{23}$. Hence $M_{23}$ is not prime.

Comment: Yes, but do not forget to mention that $23$ is of the form $4k+3$

Comment: Of course yes my bad. Thanks!